# How does the fiber bundle around a single point charge concretely look like?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry

For simplicity, let's work with the gauge group $U(1)$ and let's assume there is no external field.

Without any charge then, our fiber bundle is flat:
[image]

In the presence of an electric charge the surrounding fiber bundle is curved (i.e. curvature tensor $F_{\mu \nu} \neq 0$). I've never seen a concrete illustration of how a fiber bundle curves in the presence of a charge, although this is arguably one of the simplest situations. The picture below is my naive attempt at an illustration.

[image]

*How does the fiber bundle really look like in the presence of a single charge? (Any reference would also be great!)*

In contrast, the bundle structure around a magnetic monopole (the Hopf bundle) is discussed everywhere. But I've never seen any concrete discussion how the bundle around an electron looks like.

Comment: I do not have the time to write an complete answer right now, but in short:
It does depend, e.g. on the topology of spacetime.
What might, however, be a good reference is the book 
''Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields'' by Gregory L. Naber. You might find chapter 2 particulary helpful! For an illustration of the therein appearing ''Hopf-Bundle'', I refer you to the Wikipedia page ''https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration''. 
If there remain any questions, I'll try to answer them (if I can) another time.